# ¿Cómo agrandar el texto pero sin despalzarlo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que al darle click en el texto, este se haga más grande y se quede pagado al <hr/. Pero me surge un problema, al agrandarlo mucho se crea un espacio entre la <hr/ y el texto, asi:

```js
document.querySelector("p").addEventListener("click", agrandar_texto_sin_desplazarlo);

function agrandar_texto_sin_desplazarlo(e){
const texto = e.target;
texto.style.fontSize= Number.parseFloat(getComputedStyle(texto).fontSize) + 1 + "px";
}
```

```css
p{
font-size: 14px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
hr{
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<hr/>
<p>texto</p>
```

No se me ocurré como dejarlo pegado al <hr/, intente establecerle el top original, algo así:

```js
document.querySelector("p").addEventListener("click", agrandar_texto_sin_desplazarlo);

function agrandar_texto_sin_desplazarlo(e){
const texto = e.target;
const top_del_texto = Number.parseFloat(getComputedStyle(texto).top);
texto.style.fontSize= Number.parseFloat(getComputedStyle(texto).fontSize) + 1 + "px";
texto.style.top = top_del_texto + "px";
/*texto.style.height = Number.parseFloat(getComputedStyle(texto).height) + 1 + "px";
texto.style.width = Number.parseFloat(getComputedStyle(texto).width) + 1 + "px";*/
}
```

```css
p{
font-size: 14px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
hr{
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<hr/>
<p>texto</p>
```

Pero como pueden ver no funcionó. También se me ocurrió que en vez de cambiarle el font-size, le cambio el height y el width del texto, pero no se si luego al hacer esto el font-size cambia y además no me funciono.
He intentado buscar información de como  funciona el font-size y porqué me crea dicho espacio, pero no encontré.
Es posible lo que quiero hacer y sino alguna alternativa?

Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo el espacio que vez es del mismo **texto**, es decir, no es un `margin` ni un `padding`, es del mismo y propio del texto que escribimos en la etiqueta `p`, ya que es el ancho máximo que puede tomar un texto y sin importar el margen o ancho del `p`, y no creo que esto se pueda controlar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que se me ocurrió fue que cada vez que se hace clic al texto, el espaciado hacia abajo (`margin-bottom`) del `hr` disminuya, en donde quiere decir que en ves de que haga un espaciado hacia abajo y que el texto vaya hacia abajo, el texto va a ir hacia arriba porque el valor del `margin-bottom` del `hr` disminuirá, o sea, en vez de que el texto baje, subirá, ya que el valor del `margin-bottom` es negativo (espero se me entienda):

```js
document.querySelector("p").addEventListener("click", agrandar_texto_sin_desplazarlo);

function agrandar_texto_sin_desplazarlo(e) {
  const texto = e.target;
  texto.style.fontSize = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(texto).fontSize) + 1 + "px";
  disminuir_margin_bottom_del_hr();
}

function disminuir_margin_bottom_del_hr() {
  const hr = document.querySelector("hr");
  // el margin-bottom (que es 0), irá disminuyendo "-0.2px" cada vez que hagamos clic al texto.
  // en donde, siendo negativo, en vez de empujar al texto hacia abajo, hara lo contrario (el texto se moverá arriba).
  hr.style.marginBottom = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(hr).marginBottom) - 0.2 + "px";
}
```

```css
p{
  font-size: 14px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
hr{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<p>Texto</p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Aunque si por ejemplo ahora no tengo el hr y simplemente esta el texto como hago para que no se desplace hacia abajo? Le bajo el margin-bottom al body? Esque no me funciona si le hago eso

Comment: Pues se me ocurre disminuir el `margin-top` del `p`, así el `p` en vez de ir abajo (por el top), irá arriba, ya que el `margin-top` sería negativo (o sea ocurre lo contrario, en ves de empujar abajo, lo hace subir arriba). Es algo confuso... pero no se me ocurre otra forma de explicar xd

Comment: O sea mira, si aumento el `margin-top` del `p`, estoy haciendo un espaciado encima del `p`, en donde quiere decir que el `p` va a ir abajo porque el espaciado de arriba va a aumentar. ¿Y que ocurre al disminuir el `margin-top` en vez de aumentar?... pues, lo contrario, el `p` sube en vez de bajar.

Comment: Grax me quedo claro!